# Fix corrupted files after recovery

Tags: data-recovery, php, file-corruption

I recovered my projects files: html, css, js, php, jpg, png, txt.

When I check the files all of them seem to be in good condition except .txt and .php.

Is there's anyway to fix them? The .php files are very important (about 400 hours of coding), also I don't have a version control for them (the hard disk formatted before I did this).

#### Details:

- Corrupt: Latin text → Symbols ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS42n.png))
- File system: NTFS
- Recovery Tool: EaseUS Data Recovery

I recovered files after installing windows, after I installed Ubuntu with full installation.

Comment: How exactly are the files corrupted? What are the symptoms? Did you have to recover your project files due to former formatting? What was the filesystem? What tool did you use to recover? How do you check the files?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I edit the question , reread please